# JSON with any client and server language

Tags: jquery, json, server, client

if i choose **JSON** as data exchange format, can i use any language as server and client sides ? .

I'm currently developing a web application(php,JQuery) .My server has endpoints where i get responses in json format. I'm thinking about developing android app for same project with retrofit library which suits my need. so i think i should do upcoming projects in the same way. Am I on the right track? please suggest any better approaches if there are any.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, if you're developing your own endpoints there's no reason NOT to use JSON.  For nearly every platform you'll find some means of being able to send and receive (and decipher) JSON, so there's no concern there.  In fact, I'd say the only reason you should use XML instead of JSON is if you were a horrible person in a previous life and need to be punished.

Pretty sure XML was misnamed, as a more definitive acronym would be FML.

Answer (score 2):

Web service that provides an XML or JSON response using some **JQuery, PHP** and **MySQL**.

There are no of method through which you can create you web service

Please refer

https://trinitytuts.com/build-first-web-service-php/

https://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json